# Find numbers in text file and after that add them but see where the lowest number is as well

Tags: python, file, math, printing, numbers

How can I find all the numbers in a text file? Then I need to find the average and median of the numbers as well.

```
def main():
    file = open("grades.txt","r")
    i = file.readlines()
    numbers = file.findall(r'[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?')
    print (numbers)
main()
```

**Text file:**

```
Joe,Sammy,75
Gayle,Ujifusa,95   
Bella,Luna,65
Bob,Jones,0    
Alex,Fink,10    
Nathan,Bono,0    
Bob,Bono,0    
Edith,Bono,0    
Susie,Que,84    
Arnold,George,80    
Linda,Beth,100
```

**Output:**

Average of the grades and who has the lowest and highest grade.

Comment: Upload text file and post a link of it. Also give the output for the test file. Only then, we can help you.

Comment: can you show your file content and expected output?

Comment: Ok I edited it.

Comment: Assuming that the numbers are correctly read in `numbers`: `total = sum(numbers)`, `avg = total / len(numbers)`, `min(numbers)`, `max(numbers)`. But, looking at the code, my assumption is wrong, because you would get an `AttributeError`. There are many other questions that deal with reading from files, converting and so on.

Comment: consider using `readlines()` and `split()`. You can split on commas.

Comment: how is splitting commas going to help me find the numbers?

Comment: `split(',')` will give you a list where the last element is your number if your files all follow the format shown in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this solves your problem. PS-without numpy as you asked.

```
import re
from functools import reduce
def median(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    if n < 1:
            return None
    if n % 2 == 1:
            return sorted(lst)[n//2]
    else:
            return sum(sorted(lst)[n//2-1:n//2+1])/2.0

def main():
    file = open("grades.txt","r")
    i = file.readlines()
    num=[]
    for element in i:
        num.extend((re.findall('\d+',element)))
    results = list(map(int, num))
    print(results)
    print (reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, results) / len(results))
    print(median(results))

main()
```

Comment: Tried with this file, and it worked. Try out the solution and ask if you have any doubts. I used the numpy module to speed up stuff. -https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TL7zNuj58HIpuSFosrLzvREHaomOoN6t

Comment: I get an error:     print(np.average(results))
NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: You have to do pip install numpy first to install the numpy module. Then copy paste this code. It will work. Do you want me to give the answer without using numpy?

Comment: I would like an answer without the use of numpy.

Comment: @IosifLivadaru Hope this code helps. No need to install any modules. Accept the answer if it works fine.

Comment: It did!! Thank you!! Now I just need to find a way to print out the persons that have the lowest score and the highest score.

Comment: You can add a new question for that. I can solve it for you. You are not supposed to ask follow up questions in comments, as per SO policy.

Answer (score 2):

This should work to get a list of the numbers. No need to install anything.
This makes assumptions that the file will follow the format you've provided. If you want to find the average look at `sum()` and `len()`, and for the median you can use `len()` again with some logic handling even and odd lengths.

```
def main():
    file = open("grades.txt","r")
    i = file.readlines()
    numbers = [float(x.split(',')[-1]) for x in i]
    print (numbers)
main()
```